# How to pull all the records from elasticsearch using Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, lucene, grafana

When I am trying to pull the rawdocuments in a table from elasticsearch using Grafana, It does not show me the all the documents which are available there in elasticsearch index .No matter how many docs are in my elasticsearch index , it shows <=1000 docs only .

I guess when Grafana is firing the query for getting the docs . It is fixing the document size 1000 in query , and not using [scan and scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/scan-scroll.html) .

Is there some way possible, from where I can increase the size of documents which are getting retrieved from elasticsearch .
Can I write lucene query in query box and get all the records ? if yes what kind of query I need to specify in Grafana lucene query box , any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you want to scroll through more than 1000 docs? Is there not a filter / query you can specify to limit the list so you can find one you want?

Comment: Thanks @Torkel .. Just wanted to check on this.